# Disabling Compiler Optimizations when Building CPython

Tags: python, c, makefile, gdb

I've been following along with Philip Guo's [excellent series](http://pgbovine.net/cpython-internals.htm) about CPython's internals and have been walking through the interpreter's code with GDB. Unfortunately, GDB seems to skip around quite a bit when I step through the code, executing instructions out of order (a series of assignment operations for example, nothing fancy).

From what I understand, this is because of compiler optimizations. Indeed, CPython's `configure` file seems to default to `-O2`. This is shown to be the case when compiling Python 2.7.15 with `./configure` and `make`:

```
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Modules/python.o ./Modules/python.c
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Parser/acceler.o Parser/acceler.c
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Parser/grammar1.o Parser/grammar1.c
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Parser/listnode.o Parser/listnode.c
...
```

I tried fixing this by configuring without optimizations via `./configure CFLAGS="-g -O0"` and compiling with `make` again, which works (note the change from `-fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2` to `-fno-strict-aliasing -g -O0` on each line):

```
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O0 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Modules/python.o ./Modules/python.c
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O0 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Parser/acceler.o Parser/acceler.c
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O0 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Parser/grammar1.o Parser/grammar1.c
gcc -pthread -c -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O0 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Parser/listnode.o Parser/listnode.c
...
```

Unfortunately, GDB still jumps around when I step through the code. For completeness, here's the command I'm running with GDB:

```
gdb --args ./python test.py
```

The contents of `test.py` are just some basic arithmetic and print functions, which isn't really relevant.

My understanding of at least one of these steps must be incomplete. Am I setting the optimization flag incorrectly? Is GDB jumping between instructions due to some other reason? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: You want the `configure` setting `--with-pydebug`.

You've got an `-O3` on the command line that comes after the `-O2`, so changing the `-O2` to `-O0` doesn't do any good; the `-O3` still overrides it. You need to figure out where the `-O3` is coming from and remove it.

If you look at the generated `Makefile`, you should see something like this:

```
# Compiler options
OPT=        -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall
# ...
# Avoid assigning CFLAGS, LDFLAGS, etc. so users can use them on the
# command line to append to these values without stomping the pre-set
# values.
PY_CFLAGS=  $(BASECFLAGS) $(OPT) $(CONFIGURE_CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
```

You can, of course, just edit the generated `Makefile` to change the `-O3` to `-O0`. But if you look inside the `configure` script and `Makefile.pre`, you can see where this comes from: it's the default value, only replaced in this case:

```
case $ac_cv_prog_cc_g in
yes)
    if test "$Py_DEBUG" = 'true' ; then
    # Optimization messes up debuggers, so turn it off for
    # debug builds.
            if "$CC" -v --help 2>/dev/null |grep -- -Og > /dev/null; then
                OPT="-g -Og -Wall"
            else
                OPT="-g -O0 -Wall"
            fi
    else
    OPT="-g $WRAP -O3 -Wall"
    fi
    ;;
```

This also sets the right flags for other compilers besides `gcc`.

However, the main effect of `--with-pydebug` is to enable [`Py_DEBUG`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/intro.html#debugging-builds)—which you probably want if you're source-debugging CPython, but it is a separate thing from `-O0`, which is what you were actually asking about. So, if you want *only* `-O0`, as far as I know, the only thing you can do is edit the `Makefile` (or come up with some complicated set of env variables and `configure` arguments that tricks it into doing a debug build but then not enabling `Py_DEBUG`).

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I missed the fact that `--with-pydebug` disables optimizations. One curiosity, though, is that using `--with-pydebug` and **not** using `CFLAGS="-g -O0"`, results in the first `-O2` still showing up in the command line. The second one does change to `-O0`, though. Any idea why that still disables optimizations overall?

Comment: @jdtaylor7 Do you have a default `CFLAGS` in your gcc setup or bash profile or elsewhere?

Comment: I don't have any defaults in `.bashrc`, `.profile`, or `.bash_profile`. I haven't ever set up any gcc defaults either, so I don't believe there's a default `CFLAGS` anywhere. `echo $CFLAGS` also doesn't return anything.

Comment: @jdtaylor7 I’m assuming you’re on Linux—but what distro and version? If I have a similar enough VM to try, I can look at what might be happening. Meanwhile, the reason is works is that a later `-O` flag overrides any earlier one, so `-O0 -O3` means `-O3` (why your original fix didn’t work on its own), but `-O2 -O0` means `-O0` (why `—with-pydebug` works on its own just as well as both fixes together). This is explained somewhere in the gcc docs; I can look it up when I get a chance later.

Comment: That's correct, I'm on Arch. You've answered all my questions now, though. From your original answer I was under the impression that the highest level of optimization present on the command line was the one ultimately used, but if gcc uses the latest optimization flag then that makes complete sense. Thanks so much!